# outbound link in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, outbound

I am now checking/testing a software. To check if it's working, I have to use an existing website with outbound links. I have another site which is coded in cakephp. In this site, I have to put an anchor text to point to another website, that is outbound link. This will be used to check if the software is working. Can you help me how to add an outbound link in cakephp, im new to this. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place link using Html Helper by this Way:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Site Name', 'http://www.example.com'); ?>
```